# Rails4 using the json.array to rename Json element name

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Guys I'm trying to get the data in rails4 by Json between two tables by using the DB relation one to one

This is my Json code

```
json.array!(@users) do |user|
  json.extract! user, :id
  json.extract! user, :name
  json.extract! user, :email
  json.extract! user, :city

   # now trying to get the user nickname from the another table
  json.extract! user.nickname , name

end
```

the code `json.extract! user.nickname , name` really return the user nickname but because the field  called `name` its replace it in the Json array instead of  the user real name

so how I can rename the key name in this case? to stop overwriting the elements!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by added this line in the controller

```
format.json { render json: @users.as_json(only: [:id, :name, :email,:city, :created_at, :updated_at], include: [:second_model_name , :third_model_name]) }
```

and in `users` view folder in the file `index.json.jbuilder` I just added

```
json.array!(@users) do |user|
  json.extract! user, :id, :name, :email ,:city ,:created_at , :second_model_name, :third_model_name
end
```